# Filter destination when sending message to a (Virtual)Topic

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a scenario where messages go to a VirtualTopic and should go to the correct queue (based on a property of the message?) who are subbed to the topic.

```
[MessageForA]----->[VTopic]---->[QueueA]

[MessageForA]----->[VTopic]-X---[QueueB]
```

I've looked into filtered destinations and they don't seem to be an option as they're statically defined I need to be able to add new queues run-time.

Comment: Whats the format of your inbound message you want to check? This sounds like something for a camel filter/parser maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to enable selectorAware="true" and have your consumers register the JMS selector for the message property values.

Comment: This in theory could work however I don't think that it's possible that it's possible to dynamically assign a queue with the selectors. Examples that I've seen always have predefined queues.

The message decides the queue and queues can be added at any time when the application is running.

Comment: Might make sense to make a tool that does it .. connects as a consumer with a selector to the queue name as need then disconnect without ever receiving any messages.  Queue will get created, selector will get registered